# Azure Data Studio opens Jupyter Notebook / Lab HTML

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda

When I start Jupyter Lab or Notebook from the terminal, Azure Data Studio opens the auto-redirect HTML file instead of Firefox.

Is there a way to correct this behavior?  I'm experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 on my personal computer, but do not see this behavior on my work computer, which is a Macbook Pro.  Currently running Azure Data Studio 1.5.4.

```
jupyter                   1.0.0 
jupyter_client            5.2.4  
jupyter_console           6.0.0 
jupyter_core              4.4.0 
jupyterlab                0.35.3
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0
```

EDIT: After starting the HTML in ADS, this is the output I see in the terminal:

```
[main 11:17:33 PM] update#setState idle
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` with settings to
`text/html=firefox.desktop`
fixed the issue.
This issue is related to [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/3108) where other solutions are also provided (set a default browser for Jupyter).